# OpenCV compile error with Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, opencv, compiler-errors

Same old error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::applyColorMap(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "cv::subspaceProject(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "cv::subspaceReconstruct(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
  "cv::createEigenFaceRecognizer(int, double)", referenced from:
      _main in test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The code I was trying is:

https://gist.github.com/hihell/0520674421fe0cb26d38

I already changed C++ standard library to "Compiler Default" but the error is still there.

However, other simple code like showing a picture or open the camera works fine with the same settings.

Versions:

- The OpenCV was installed by brew, version 2.4.8
- Xcode version 5.1.1
- OSX version 10.9.3 Could anyone help me?

Any help or hint is more than welcome

Answer (score 0):

You need to indicate the header and library search path properly.

It seems that you have correctly set the header path.
To set the library search path, do as follows:

1. Find the "Library Search Paths" settings in Xcode of the project. `Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Library Search Paths`. Then in Debug or Release, add your OpenCV library path. (In my case, it's /usr/local/lib.)
2. Find: `Buid Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`, add the *.dylib files.
   In my case, I add:

   - libopencv_contrib.2.4.9.dylib
   - libopencv_core.2.4.9.dylib
   - libopencv_highgui.2.4.9.dylib
   - libopencv_imgproc.2.4.9.dylib

*Note, libopencv_contrib.2.4.9.dylib is essential to the functions you mentioned, others may also be needed.*

By the way, if you have problem to add the header files, it's just the same. Add them under `Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Header Search Paths`.